# Bypass proxy server between iPhone and wifi in a mac

Tags: iphone, macos, proxy

I want to monitor the network usages of an iPhone from a mac. So I want to configure a proxy server in my mac and connect wifi through this proxy from iPhone. So that i can see the network request logs.

Please help me to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BurpSuite** is the easiest way to achieve this. It is an intercepting Proxy, which lets you inspect and modify traffic between your browser and the target application. It monitors the Http Requests with request and response data.

Download it from [here](http://portswigger.net/burp/download.html)

Answer (score 1):

I used [VisualProxy](http://www.visualproxy.org/) for this purpose - it's easy to set up on the phone and computer too.

Comment: where is the download link?